# console.log not working in react and graphql

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I am learning graphql with the tuto: 
https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/0-introduction/

all i fine until I just want to add some console.log !!
Outside the class body console.log() is ok. Inside it is not ok... 
I got message error while compiling.

```
class LinkList extends Component { ...


console.log('from LinkList')

render() {
return (


Syntax error: Unexpected token (158:9)

156 |   }
157 | 
> 158 | console.log('from LinkList')
    |          ^
159 |   render() {
160 |     return (
161 |       <Query query={FEED_QUERY} variables= 
{this._getQueryVariables()}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your component is a class component, you can't use `console.log` like that. Instead, put it inside `render`, above `return`.

```
render() {
    console.log("foo");
    return (
    ....
```